# Cant pull/push git

Tags: git, ssh

I dont know what happened but I am not able to push/pull from my git repository. I think it might be an ssh issue, since I am also not able to ssh to any other server machine.

Here are some Outputs that might help

`git pull
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

`netstat -ntpl
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37034         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20428/GoogleTalkPlu
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11767           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4179/skype

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -

tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN`      -

Any ideas ??

Comment: First thing first: what an '`shh -vvv yourServer`' shows? (Ie let's check the `ssh` config before doing any `git` command)

Comment: If you can not use ssh fix this first.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall which is blocking ssh?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply gentlemen. The problem is that currently when I use the Internet from my office the problem vanishes but from the device which I use to connect from the home, the problem appears. I will update this when I will get home. :)